# Generating a built angular index.html page with all the CSS rules used by the templates?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-cli, uncss

In order to run [uncss](https://github.com/uncss/uncss) to remove unused css rules I need to generate a single page containing all the the css rules used by the angular templates.  I think [Rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron) might fit this usecase, but was wondering whether it's possible to do the same with the Angular CLI?

For example if we run `ng build` angular will generate a `dist/index.html` file with the custom element selectors in the `dist/index.html` file.  However this cannot be targeted with [uncss](https://github.com/uncss/uncss) because the template has not been rendered.  It is still represented by for example `<app-root>`, thus [uncss](https://github.com/uncss/uncss) cannot see the css rules applied by the `<app-root>` template.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by default all the compiled CSS and js files will be generated into dist folder via angular cli.If required, you can configure this using angular-cli.json present in your project. As you can see in below sample of **index.html**, it contains the path for all the css and JS files. Usually it creates one css file, as it's good to load entire css in one request.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My APP</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link href="styles.3e523e6b74c68b0940ab.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.5d1afc94d5922f9e85f3.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.45da1a3263e1321501bf.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.4d46a754e6ffe4a0ff23.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.cec0d2d86e8c98d02873.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also instruct cli to separate any vendor specific CSS/js into separate files. Follow the [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli) to know more about configuration.

Since, you would be specifying all your css and js in [uncss](https://github.com/uncss/uncss), so you can go with dist folder content.

Comment: Hi - I edited my question a bit just make make sure it's clear.  Just want to make sure none of the css class names used in the templates are altered by the build.  Thanks again.

Comment: Improved my answer and i don't think any css class name will be altered by build. They will be included as it is.

Comment: Hi - I updated the question a bit.  I don't think the normal build solves the use case.  Perhaps something like rendertron might.